# How to use a Script Task to Download One or More Files from FTP?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I've created a Script Task in my SSIS 2012 package that needs to grab files from a FTP server and store them on the local server's hard drive.  The code I've written in the script task s as follows:

```
Public Sub Main()
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '
    Const localFile As String = "C:\InboundOrders\*.*"
    Const remoteFile As String = "/remote/folder/filename.pgp"
    Const host As String = "ftp://ftp1.commerceub.com"
    Const user As String = "ourusername"
    Const pw As String = "ourpassword"

    Dim URI As String = host & remoteFile
    Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), 
    FtpWebRequest)

    ftp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pw)
    ftp.KeepAlive = False
    ftp.UseBinary = True
    ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    Using response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse, 
    System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localFile, IO.FileMode.Create)
                Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                Dim read As Integer = 0
                Do
                    read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                Loop Until read = 0
                responseStream.Close()
                fs.Flush()
                fs.Close()
            End Using
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using
        response.Close()
    End Using
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

When I run the package, I receive an error stating:

```
DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, 
   Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, 
   Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder 
   binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, 
   CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,    
   Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

What should I do to remedy the above error?  Thanks for your help and guidance.

UPDATE:  I specified a file that is actually on the FTP server in my code.  I receive the same error.  Is there a different approach I should take?

Comment: Instead of `remoteFile As String = "/remote/folder/*.*"`, what happens if you specify one file, like `remoteFile As String = "/remote/folder/MyFile.xls"`

Comment: Also, there is no way that `fs As New IO.FileStream(localFile` is valid. localFile is is \*.\* which is not a valid file name in windows. This could also be why it's failing.

Comment: I won't have the ability to know what the filenames will be each time this is run.  As such, I need the program to download all the files in the containing FTP directory.

Comment: Right, but to troubleshoot your problem, ensure you can download one file without trouble. Then attempt to download multiple files